# Word 2003 vba cannot change bookmark font

Tags: vba, ms-word

The following code does not work

```
objDoc.Bookmarks("SomeBookMark").Range.Font.Bold = True
objDoc.Bookmarks("SomeBookMark").Range.Text = GetSomeText()
objDoc.Bookmarks("SomeBookMark").Range.Font.Bold = True
```

When I run the code the text that is retrieved by GetSomeText() still has the default font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just style the bookmarks? 
I searched for this in the past and also didn't find a proper solution back then. 
However, since a bookmark represents a fixed field in a text template, usually the format shouldn't change so easily.

I'm sorry to put this in the reply field, but I can't find the "comment" button :-s